# CloudBlockBlob.DownloadTextAsync call sometimes fails with outofmemory exception

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Question is how can I ensure that above call will always succeed. Should I limit the size of blob being uploaded. Should I check blob container size before uploading? What are the limits for containers and block blobs. 
New to Blob storage what are the maximum limits for uploading and downloading block blobs.

The code used by me

```
       protected async Task<string> ReadBlockBlobText(CloudBlockBlob blockBlob)
    {
        var exists = await blockBlob.ExistsAsync();
        if ( exists )
            return await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: How large is the blob that you're trying to download?

Comment: Could you please share the code about how you use the CloudBlockBlob.DownloadTextAsync method? Could you please tell us the size of the blob storage you download when you faced this error? Is your application running on a 32 bit Windows?

Comment: Size was 108mb. This test passes first time. Fails second time. Passing and failing is random.  Its a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that your blob exceeds the memory allowance for the application, try and use a `Stream` instead with the `DownloadToStreamAsync` method and read lazily.

Comment: Thanks I will try that

Comment: Link which tells us sizes of storage limits https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/07/08/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity/